# How do I move from 1 upstream php-fpm to many with different URL routes?

Tags: php, nginx

Using Docker, I currently have 2 containers - nginx and PHP 7.0 php-fpm.

I now need to expand this for new code on PHP 7.2.

I've added new `upstream` entries.

```
upstream php-70 {
    server php-70:9000;
}
upstream php-72 {
    server php-72:9000;
}
```

The current config for this service is :

```
# By default rewrite all other requests to index.php
location / {
    # Allows the Client to send cookies in CORS requests
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true" always;

    # Headers the Server can read from the Client in CORS requests
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With" always;

    # Headers the Client can read from the Server in CORS requests
    add_header "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" "Link" always;

    # What requests methods can be used in a CORS request
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE" always;

    # What origins (domains) can make CORS requests
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*" always;

    rewrite .+ /index.php?$args?;
}

location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

    expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
    fastcgi_pass   php-70;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS $https if_not_empty;

    include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

    # Allows the Client to send cookies in CORS requests
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true" always;

    # Headers the Server can read from the Client in CORS requests
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With" always;

    # Headers the Client can read from the Server in CORS requests
    add_header "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" "Link" always;

    # What requests methods can be used in a CORS request
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE" always;

    # What origins (domains) can make CORS requests
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "$http_origin" always;
}
```

What I now need is the URLs that start with `/v0/`, `/v1/`, or `/v2/` to go to php-70, and if the URLs start with `/v3/`, then they go to php-72.

The config was given to us and we're not experts on nginx, so if there is anything more sensible on how to do this, the better.

Comment: Do you have issues for achieving this? Or you just want to know if there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve it. Basically, currently, everything goes to 1 upstream PHP 7.0 server. I need to split PHP 7.0 and 7.2 based upon the url prefix.

Comment: Add a location block like this: location ^~ /v3/*/*.php$ {}. Using the same content in this new location block as you did, except for the line: fastcgi_pass. Of course, you should use php-72 as the value of fastcgi_pass in new location block.